# Showing uniform convergence of sequence $\langle\frac{x^n}n\rangle$

Tags: uniform-convergence

Show that the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}n$ on $[0,1]$ converges uniformly to $0$.

I am able to show that the given sequence converges point-wise to $0$. Now, trying to using the Cauchy's principle to show uniform convergence i am unable to find a suitable $m$. Need some hint please.

Comment: You need not to use the Cauchy criterion - it is sufficient that give an upper bound of $|f_n(x)-0|$ which only depends on $n$. It is easy to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we need is $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0,n\to\infty$

Now $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|\frac{x^n}{n}|\le\frac{1}{n}\to 0,n\to\infty$

Thus we have uniform convergence.

Comment: I get this. is it that this cannot be approached using cauchy's principle ?

Comment: it can be, but it is more complicated. My ethic is to do the least as is necessary. :)

Comment: In the same question if the domain is changed to $[-\infty ,\infty]$, how do we evaluate it then ?

Comment: On $(-\infty,\infty)$, we would not be able to find a uniform bound, and we would not have uniform convergence.